# How to use Fragment same as an Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have followed this tutorial for create a good tabs in activity http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

But it use Fragment and in fragment is not possibile to use any normal code es:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or one simple button click

```
btnSum =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btnSum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuthTask = new TaskAsincrono();
                mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
            }
        });
```

Nothing work on Fragment, its possibile?

I need tabs because the activity has multiple function, the result is good but at level code no, 1 Fragment has Login with button, text but if i call button click not work ex:

```
Button btnSum =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btnSum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

[image]

[image]

Fragment Tab2:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab2"
    tools:context="net.appsite.Tab2">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_x="49dp"
        android:layout_y="226dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_x="114dp"
        android:layout_y="280dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Tab2.jar:

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment{

    public Tab2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //ANY NORMAL CODE HERE NOT WORK, BUT IN NORMAL ACTIVITY WORK!
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
    }
}
```

This is my first application with android, plese help me.

Comment: A fragment does not extend `Context`, hence you cannot use `this`. You can use `getContext()` or `getActivity()` if you need a context, e.g. to show a `Toast`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use activity context for showing `Toast`

To add click listener to `Button` use the Fragment's `view.findviewByID()`

your Fragment class should look like:

```
    public class Tab2 extends Fragment{

   View view;

    public Tab2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //ANY NORMAL CODE HERE NOT WORK, BUT IN NORMAL ACTIVITY WORK!
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //use activity context
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
       Button btnSum =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button3);  // get Button with the view object
        btnSum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

       return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: App crash after open activity =(
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: you button ID is `button3` check the layout.xml

Answer (score 2):

In Fragment "this" wont work, You have to get context of parent activity like "getActivity()" or passing context from activity to fragment.

Your code goes like this

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Tab2 Activity Looks like this:

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment{
private View mRootView;

public Tab2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}




public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  mRootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container,false);

   Button btnSum =(Button)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btnSum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //Your action goes here
            }
          });  

        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do `getActivity().findViewById(..)` and `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` when in `Fragment`

It is because `findViewById` is defined on `Context` and `Toast` expects first parameter to be `Context`. Since `Activity` extends `Context` indirectly, it works. But in `Fragment` you need to get the context. One way is to do `getActivity()` in `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks and same to you!!

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment` is not the exact same as `Activity` please refer to [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for more info

---

Also `Fragment` is not a `Context` , see more info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) So you can't use `this` when passing a `Context` but instead use:

```
getActivity()
```

or

```
 getApplicationContext()
```

---

Also binding views need to be done in you_fragment's `onViewCreated` method like that:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
    Button btnSum =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button4); 
    // note that button4 should be existing in fragment_tab2
    btnSum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                }
             });

             // other views binding code
             // and other code
     return view;
}
```